Does a chord of 2 keys separated by 3 semitones have a name?
I'm looking the chords of a song, and one of them has 2 keys separated by 3 semitones. Usually chords used in songs are listed among the 115+ chords listed in FL Studio with specific names, but this isnt there.
Does a chord of 2 keys separated by 3 semitones have a name?

This, as it stands, isn't very clear. One could argue that, for example, G and Bb could constitute C7, were there a C somewhere else in the bar. Others, inc. myself, would argue that a dyad isn't a chord in any case.

Are they a minor third apart or some other three-semitone interval?

I think here, knowing which song, and where in it, will be relevant to the question.

In addition, knowing why you want the answer is relevant. Are you trying to analyze the song, or are you just translating from one notation (or transcribing by ear) to something simple you can put to e.g. ultimate-guitar.com?

Two notes, in general, are not a chord. They are an interval. You need three or more notes to have a chord.

If by two keys you mean two notes then two keys (or notes) separated by 3 semitones is considered a minor chord with no 5th.
Some examples would be
A and C: A minor
C and Eb: C minor
The identification of these would also depend on the context they appear in. For example, there may be a different bass note beneath them.

I think I wrote the question wrongly. How would you call a chord made of A# and G?

We would spell it Bb and G, and this answer still applies.  That would be G minor.

How do you notate a chord with no fifth on a lead sheet?

"a minor chord with no 5th": it could also be a major chord with no root, though it's rather less likely.

@HNHN you normally don't.  Omitting the fifth is generally optional, and adding a fifth isn't normally going to hurt anything.  In general, lead sheets serve as guidance, not as a full specification of exactly what must be played.  It's generally entirely acceptable to play a seventh chord, for example, when a triad is given.  But if you want to indicate the omission of the fifth you can write "no 5" or something like that.

@phoog: I wouln't say that it's "generally acceptable" to replace e.g. a G triad with G7 or GMaj7, nor to replace a Gm triad with a Gm7.  While there are certainly many places where a seventh chord would work or even be desirable but a triad is notated anyhow, but there are many others where a seventh would be Just Plain Wrong.  Incluing a fifth, by contrast, is almost always tolerable in the absence of a specific notation forbiding it, because there are relatively few situations where it would be problematic, such as when e.g. a diad is deliberately ambiguous about whether it's...

...the bottom two notes of a C major CEG triad or the top two notes of an ACE traid.

This could be called a "minor dyad" and is treated in isolation as a minor chord with no fifth.  The fifth of chords is commonly omitted because it does not determine the chord quality unless it has been altered.
Minor dyads are defined here as "two notes played together at the same time that are three semitones apart."
There are also major dyads, two notes 4 semitones apart, which are treated as major chords with no fifth.
Some would argue that a dyad (two notes played together) is not technically a chord.

Most people regard two notes as an interval and not a chord.  Typically, as others have mentioned, you need a tonic, third, and fifth (and/or variations and adjustments thereof) as the minimum for a chord.  This might be "old" thinking that relies upon the work of 18th-century composers, but there are reasons why intervals aren't chords.
For one, again made clear by the responses, two notes is not sufficient to differentiate their exact "flavor" without additional context.  This is only relevant to the speaking or written (not the staff) language of music because the notes themselves do not care what we call them.  But there are too many possibilities for the interval you describe to be able to definitively say that they represent a 7th chord or whatever without knowledge of the context in which they appear.
And by the way, if you assume that the lower note is the tonic, then two notes with three semi-tones between them is a major third interval.

I suggest you re-think and re-write your final sentence: a major third interval contains four semitones, two for each of the two full tones that can be regarded as composing it.
